# How to disable video background playing when leaving cordova android app

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have an issue with running my Android app in the background. It's cordova based with app framework.

There are YouTube videos in it and Google won't allow for background playing, meaning that if you leave the app with the home button while the video is playing, the app will not stop playing i.e. the music will continue.

There's already a similar issue on Stack Overflow, but I can't comment on it and it does not work for me. I tried the `keeprunning = false` but that won't work with Cordova.

Comment: Every time I find the correct wording of the question I have... there are 0 answers :(

Comment: Did you end up solving that? I have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @MattKenefick Totally agree with you. Did you solved this issue?